# How do I move our LinkedIn App to another LinkedIn Account

Tags: linkedin-api

The developer who created our production LinkedIn Application added it under his personal LinkedIn account via developer.linkedin.com.  We would like to move this application to our company LinkedIn account.  Because we have hundreds of customers who have already authenticated using this application, we would like to move it rather than just creating a new application from scratch.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This is a good place to start: __[developer.linkedin.com/support/faq](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/faq)__ check the "Where can I find my API key?" and "Can I reset my application's Client Secret value?". If you have the code or access to it, you should find in it those values... other wise, your developer is the owner of your application and, well you may be tied up...

Comment: Did you figure it out? I need to move one too.

Comment: Hey David, see my answer below.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how we ended up solving this one...

We did not need to change the API Key, all we needed was designate a different LinkedIn account to be the admin for the App.  The key for us was having cooperation from the old admin of the app who had left our company.  Here are the steps we followed:

- Sue New = New Admin
- John Old = Old Admin

Sue New does this...

```
1. Log into personal LinkedIn account
2. Send a request to connect to John Old's LinkedIn account
```

John Old does this...

```
1. Log to personal LinkedIn account and accept the request to cnnect from Sue New
2. Go to developer.linkedin.com
3. Select "My Apps" at the top
4. Select the App
5. On the left, select "Roles"
6. Add Sue New an Admin.
```

Once Sue New confirms access as the LinkedIn App administrator, remove John Old's role.